# how do i add a responsive carousel when in mobile view in react?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

so , basically I need the carousel when my website is in mobile view and when it is in desktop view the carousel should convert into normal div and i also need it in react and I am using bootstrap not react-bootstrap.  [for reference see 'why to choose us ? ' section of the page.](https://wtfup.me/partner)

I tried to add bootstrap carousel but it works in all view as a carousel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you do, is build 2 different Components, one for the mobile view and another for the Web view.

Switching between the 2 views can be done by checking the window screen size:

```
const Main=()=>{
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
    ...
    if(width < 600)
    return <MobileView/>
    else return <WebView/>

}
```

Also this way, editing each view on it's own will be much simpler for later.